# How to delete rows in DB with spring data (jpa) in blocks

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

**Situation:**

- I have a table/entity of Persons (name, sex, email).
- My application contains 1.000.000.000 persons
- I want to delete all male persons (I expect that 500.000.000 persons will be deleted)

**Naive solution:**

I create a method in my PersonRepositoy with the name:

```
deleteBySex(Sex sex)
```

and just call it with Sex.MALE

**Problem:**

during the execution of the deletion the database is blocked, no new entries can be added.

**Theoretical Solution:**

Repeat until all findAnyBySex(Sex sex) returns no entries:

- delete first 1000 entries with sex = Sex.MALE
- give other operations to execute their queries (e.g. add new persons)

**Question:**

Is there is some way in spring data to delete data in small blocks/chunks/bulks without implementing it manually or with as less manual implementation as possible? (The operation don't need to be transactional, some async execution is sufficient)

Comment: Maybe think about changing your locking-policies for the duration of the deletion.

Comment: Thank's for the interesting idea. Do you know a good way how to change the locking policies temporarily in a spring data application?

Comment: For this kind of stuff I would work straight with JDBC. Also: what database are you using?

Comment: It's MSSQL. I hoped that spring data supports that in an independent way of database vendor.